# If lazy loading is bad, why not keep it disabled?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lazy-loading, laravel-8

I'm following along with Laracasts' [Laravel 8 from Scratch course](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch/episodes/30?autoplay=true), and have been introduced to the concept of lazy loading to run queries via Laravel's Eloquent ORM.

Laravel 8 comes with the option to [disable lazy loading](https://laravel-news.com/disable-eloquent-lazy-loading-during-development) on an app-wide basis, but that same page recommends to only do so during development, implying that there's a benefit to lazy loading in production.

However in the Laracasts course, Jeffrey Way's general approach to lazy loading seems to be to always avoid it by running queries that force eager loading. This confuses me, because if it is the case that lazy loading should be avoided, why not just disable it completely and force yourself to *always* eager load queries from the database? Is this a good idea to do, and if not, why not?

Comment: It's possible that some data structures benefit from lazy-loading - and some don't. Having one overall answer cannot cover all scenarios and always be correct.  Loading all of the orders a customer has made doesn't make sense, but you may want all of the contact details for a customer up front.

Comment: @NigelRen Absolutely zero data-structures benefit from lazy-loading. Lazy-loading  is a RAD benefit, not an algorithmic/CS-theoretical benefit.

Comment: Perhaps because it's too new? After all, the feature was only introduced a few weeks ago.

Comment: @aynber Lazy-loading in Larvel works very similarly as in other ORMs like EF and Hibernate. It's certainly nothing new from an SE perspective.

Comment: @Dai I meant the option to disable lazy loading. That feature was only introduced into Laravel a few weeks ago.

Comment: @aynber This article about the new feature explains the motivation behind it: https://laravel-news.com/disable-eloquent-lazy-loading-during-development - it's to help identify and resolve "`N+1` lazy-loading" problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because *in practice* you might be tweaking something in production (as you can edit PHP files *in vivo*) and if you make a change that causes data to be lazy-loaded without you realising then at least the program will still work (albeit more slowly compared to if it were eager-loaded), instead of crashing and damaging the end user-experience.

The situation is comparable to compiling a C/C++ program with assertions enabled only in `DEBUG` builds instead of release builds: the assertions help you catch bugs during development, but in production use you *probably* want the program to keep on running instead of crashing (more precisely: breaking / "*asserting*"), unless the assertion is an important sanity-check, of course.

---

Another way of looking at it via a flow-chart:

- The PHP script wants to use some data which was not eager-loaded. **Is it running in production?**

  - **Yes.** Then lazy-load the data. [It's slow](https://jesperjarlskov.dk/eager-loading-n1-problem), but at least it will work.

    - Success! The user never notices anything is wrong! (other than a slightly longer page load time)
  - **No**. Crash/break/invoke-debugger to inform the developer that they need to eager-load this data first.

    - Success! Assuming the developer added an eager-load then now the program won't need to lazy-load in production.

Conversely, if it didn't:

- The PHP script wants to use some data which was not eager-loaded. **Is it running in production?**

  - **Yes.** Crash because the data isn't available.

    - Your users are frustrated that the software doesn't work. They leave a 1-star review online. New prospects elect to use a competitor's product. You never overcome the reputational damage. You die alone and penniless.

Comment: Lazy loading doesn't mean don't load it, it means load it when it's accessed rather than up front.  So the idea that the app won't work with lazy loading isn't applicable.

Comment: @NigelRen I never said that the app won't work with lazy-loading. I'm saying the app will crash/fail if lazy-loading is disabled _if_ the application dereferences a member that is not eager-loaded.

Comment: When does the dereferencing take place?

Comment: @NigelRen Whenever you use a Laravel model object member that triggers it: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships (a "dereference" is a general CS term, not specific to PHP/Laravel - in a general sense it means to _resolve a reference_, which could be a pointer (in C), an object-reference (in Java), or a remote data (in the context of an ORM like Laravel).

Comment: I'm confused by your answer then, do you mean *if* you change lazy-loading in production it can fail or that if you develop your application to use lazy-loading it can fail.

Comment: @NigelRen (in my opinion) you should always be developing with lazy-loading disabled. In production your Laravel boot/configuration script would enable lazy-loading - that way in production it _won't_ fail. But you _want_ it to fail when developing so you can see where-and-when to eager-load data for improved performance (and to avoid the dreaded "N+1" lazy-load situation). The lazy-loading option should not be changed _whilst in_ production. All you need is `Model::preventLazyLoading(! app()->isProduction());` inside your `public function boot()`.

Comment: So in summation, _Develop without backup (lazy-loading), run with backup_.

Comment: @JaredFarrish exactly!

Comment: If I intuit this correctly, this means that development predicates a configuration that forces the state to be looked up at-need, which is good for a variety of reasons. What I'm wondering is, in the case of receiving an object that proxies a state representation (a deferred computation), lazy-loading becomes a backstop for a (nominally) actively configured object _that didn't compute/resolve at-need_. In the context of Laravel or even PHP ORM, doesn't that imply that when the object was sourced and should've eager loaded/computed, it didn't and (probably?) threw an exception, try again?

Comment: This is a really poor reason for not using lazy loading. It should be enabled by default - allowing engineers to deploy code to production that hasn't been well thought-through, and creates pain points for users is an awful way to develop - and I sure as hell wouldn't want those sorts of engineers on my team(s).

Fact is that disabling lazy loading means you'll catch it in development, not just when it goes to production.

However, whilst this is a far better way to develop, disabling lazy-loading globally for Laravel developers is a sure fire way to crash and burn a LOT of projects.

Comment: @Dai then explain yourself better, because what you're advocating for is very, very bad advice.

Comment: @Oddman My post specifically advocates _fast-failure_ in dev, and _graceful degredation_ in prod - how is that bad advice?

Comment: @Dai Your very first sentence seems to postulate that direct modification to production is somehow acceptable, and that this is the basis for the remainder of your argument.